# Using DataContractSerializer and XmlSerializer both in a single service

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontractserializer, xmlserializer

I have a WCF service something like :

```
[ServiceContract]
ServiceInterface
{
    [OperationContract]
    FirstResponse FirstOperation(){}

    [OperationContract]
    SecondResponse SecondOperation(){}
}
```

I want the response in XML at the client side . As per my knowledge it uses `DataContractSerializer` . BUt in FirstReponse I have a data member which i want as attribute in XML . I have read though `DataContractSerializer` doesn't support it. The solution is to use `XmlSerializer` but that would compromise efficiency . 
So I want to know is it possible to use `XmlSerializer` for just one operation and `DataContractSerializer` for the rest of service. If yes how? Consider the FirstResponse class as:

```
[DataContract]
public class FirstResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public int id;

    [DataMember]
    public string type1;
}
```

I want id as an attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify that `XmlSerializer` should be used for serialization by decorating your method with the [XmlSerializerFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.xmlserializerformatattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[ServiceContract]
ServiceInterface
{
    [OperationContract]
    [XmlSerializerFormat]
    FirstResponse FirstOperation(){}

    [OperationContract]
    SecondResponse SecondOperation(){}
}
```

Edit: I forgot to mention that if you want to serialize `FirstResponse` with XmlSerializer, then there is no need for the `DataContract` / `DataMember` attributes on that type. You can set it up for XmlSerializer as follows:

```
public class FirstResponse
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int id;

    [XmlElement]
    public string type1;
}
```

You can vary the [serialization attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) based on how you want your type serialized. If you have members that you do not want serialized at all, then you would need to specify `[XmlIgnore]` on those members, since `XmlSerializer` is opt-out unlike `DataContractSerializer`.